# How to set lowercase_table_name

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-8.0

I've been trying to setup `lower_case_table_names` for ages in MySQL 8.0 without success. What is the procedure to set this up in 8.0?

In previous versions of mysql I was able to override the variable in `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` by adding the following lines:

```
[mysql] 
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

But when I try to restart the server / service mysql does not restart.
In the past all mysql servers had this setting working fine I just don`t know how to do the same in 8.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The server variable **[`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)** is described in the relevant documentation page:

**[Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)**, where it also mentions:

> [`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) can only be configured when initializing the server. **Changing the [`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) setting after the server is initialized is prohibited.**

Some more details appear in the linked page about [server variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names):

> It is prohibited to start the server with a `lower_case_table_names` setting that is different from the setting used when the server was initialized. The restriction is necessary because collations used by various data dictionary table fields are based on the setting defined when the server is initialized, and restarting the server with a different setting would introduce inconsistencies with respect to how identifiers are ordered and compared.

Comment: lower_case_table_names is set to 1 on windows systems and lower_case_table_names is set to 0 on linux systems or the other way around, i just know they set it diff by default, i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinit MySQL data directory.
According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html `lower_case_table_names` can only be configured when initializing the server.

If you are running Ubuntu than you can do it using this script https://github.com/igrmk/ubuntu-reinit-mysql.

Please note that your data will be DESTROYED!
So create a backup before running it.